# Can't enroll finger print with Windows Hello

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint, sensors

I have a HP ProBook 4540s running Windows 10 Pro and I can't enroll my fingerprint.

It allows me to start registering  my fingerprint:

[image]

But it always gets stuck there. The driver is installed. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Windows 10 supports Windows Hello, a driver should not be required, supporting devices should simply work.  Do you normally have a problem using fingerprint sensors?  There are cases, where people, simply don’t have the fingerprint required to use fingerprint sensors

Comment: The sensor could simply be defective. This can unfortunately happen even on new devices.